# Pandas json_normalize converts ints to floats when there are null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use `json_normalize` to flatten some json into a pandas dataframe. When there are no null values, it works as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

json = [{"test": 1}, {"test": 2}, {"test": 3}]

df = json_normalize(json)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
   test
0     1
1     2
2     3
```

However, if I change `{"test": 3}` to `{"test": None}` then the following the int64 data objects are converted to float64 type:

```
   test
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   NaN
```

has anyone found a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is because integers can't be of NaN type.

One workaround could be to keep everything as a string:

```
json = [{"test": "1"}, {"test": "2"}, {"test": "None"}]
```

and you'll get

```
   test
0     1
1     2
2  None
```

Comment: Agreed, if you want to keep None, convert to String. Otherwise you could also remove NaNs and then convert back to integers